# Is there any performance issue using comments in the loop in java, javascript, and c#?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, comments, conventions

Is there any performance issue using comments in the loop in java, javascript, and c#?
I don't think it will be a problem, but I would like to know how do you work.

```
/* 
Case 1
This is Loop for something.
a : ace
b : bee
*/
for (i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    /* 
        Case 2
        This is Loop for something.
        a : ace
        b : bee

    */
    var a = "1";
    var b = "2";
}
```

Comment: Compilers should remove the comments.

Comment: Might take a picosecond more for parsing the source text initially, compared to if there were no comments at all. Will not matter.

Comment: JavaScript always has the best performance because it does not require wasting time in a compilation process + the loading process of rfessources, etc...

Comment: @MisterJojo JS always has the worst performance because it is compiled on the fly, therefore browsers effectively run an entire compiler. Furthermore JS is not statically typed which slows things down, and has a very small base library requiring huge downloads on the fly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any performance issue using comments in the loop in java, javascript, and c#? I don't think it will be a problem, but I would like to know how do you work.

It costs a very small amount of time for the compiler (Java or C#) or runtime (JavaScript) to parse and discard a comment.  The fact that it appears in a loop is definitely irrelevant in compiled languages such as Java and C#, and probably irrelevant in most JavaScript implementations, too.  There is no runtime cost in the compiled languages because there is no representation of comments in the compiler output.

The compile-time costs of comments are miniscule compared to the time savings and correctness benefits that well commented code provides to code maintainers.  Put comments in the places that are most meaningful.  Although they are not completely free, the tiny cost of appropriate comments is in no way worth any concern.

Comment: Indeed in real world comments have zero impact on performance because they are stripped out during bundling/minification server side for browsers (nodeJs is likely to see comments at least in some if not most code so).